# assign the value the variable to my object identifier json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

first, excuse my english, isn't very good.

I'm creating a json object like this:

```
data = {UUIDDevice:
               {"Latitude": Latitude, 
                "Longitude": Longitude, 
                "Model": ModelDevice, 
                "IDDevice": UUIDDevice, 
                "Platform": PlatformDevice
               }
            };
```

My problem is that the object identifier: UUIDevice does not take the value of the variable, only puts UUIDevice like that:

```
{ UUIDDevice: //<--Here should there be a text like: 35e620c299bc087a 
 { Latitude: '6.2720517',
   Longitude: '-75.5478177',
   Model: 'XT1033',
   IDDevice: '35e620c299bc087a',
   Platform: 'Android' 
 }
}
```

I was trying with a variable as string to later, apply to it JSON.parse(), well, thats works fine, but returns the object identifier into quotes, so when I try to get a property from my object like: data.UUIDevice.Model happens an error: "Cannot read property "Model" "

I hope you can help me with this, I think that can be about concatenation in the object identifier but I don't know how would be.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to have a reference to an object? If so, that is not possible, because JSON is for primitive datatypes only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {}
data[UUIDDevice]=
               {"Latitude": Latitude, 
                "Longitude": Longitude, 
                "Model": ModelDevice, 
                "IDDevice": UUIDDevice, 
                "Platform": PlatformDevice
               };
```

Comment: As I understand his problem, he have a value in the UUIDDevice variable, and he wants that value as key in the data object

Comment: so I mean just data[UUIDDevice]!